# Will a live USB for a Mac run on a chromebook or windows computer?

Tags: usb, unix

I created a live Kali USB for my Chromebook which single boots ubuntu mate. I was wondering, if I made a live kali(or other linux distribution) for booting on a Mac, so using .img instead of .iso would the .img still work on my Chromebook?

In simpler terms will a live USB for OSX still work on a Chromebook or windows.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "linux" under tags not "UNIX" this is my first post so I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Normally you would use the edit link to edit your post, however in this case the tags are synonymised [linux] → [unix].

Answer (score 1):

No, the disk should still be able to boot.

There isn't actually a difference between the operating system in the .img and .iso. They're just different ways of storing the same information.

Kali(or any other *nix) distro is an operating system, just as Windows and OS X are. Whether or not an operating system will run on a computer is solely dependent on the hardware, not the software already on the computer.

Answer (score 0):

If your USB "drive" is large enough you should be able to partition it into two volumes. Then install a linux distribution that will run on Mac hardware on one and your ubuntu for your Chromebook on the other. I'm not familiar enough with the boot process of the Chromebook to know if there would be any other snags.